# Sapi how to get elements inside tag elements

Tags: c++, sapi

I have a grammar like this

```
 <grammar xml:lang="en-US" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar" tag   format="semantics/1.0" root="number" mode="voice">
 <rule id="number" scope="public">
  <one-of>
        <item>1<tag>out.string="one"</tag><tag>out.Name="first"</tag></item>
        <item>2<tag>out.string="two"</tag><tag>out.Name="second"</tag></item>
  </one-of>
 </rule>
</grammar>
```

Can anyone help me how to access the elements inside the tag elements too.
For eg .If the recognizer recognize 1
then it should give 1 ,one and first.

Currently am using

```
ISpRecoResult* pResult = spevent.RecoResult();

LPWSTR pszCoMemResultText = NULL;
_hr = pResult->GetText(SP_GETWHOLEPHRASE, SP_GETWHOLEPHRASE, TRUE,&pszCoMemResultText,NULL);
```

pszCoMemResultText is giving me "1" or "2" based on the recogniztion

Thanks

Comment: `<tag>` isn't a valid [SAPI 5.3 grammar element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Do you perhaps mean the `propid` attribute or `valstr` attribute?

Comment: Eric am new to sapi  , Am not that familiar with propid and valstr .My aim is to return list of key value pairs when some text is recognized by the recognizer.I thought above grammar xml will help me to accomplish it but no luck.In which version of sapi <tag> is a valid grammar element?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a W3C grammar, not a SAPI grammar.  Silly me.

That data is stored in the [SPPHRASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125122%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) structure, not the text, so you would retrieve it like this:

```
ISpRecoResult* pResult = spevent.RecoResult();

SPPHRASE* pphrase;
hr = pResult->GetPhrase(&pphrase);
// your code here
CoTaskMemFree(pphrase);
```

Now, I haven't used W3C grammars with C++, so I'm not *entirely* sure if it works the same way as it does with SAPI grammars, but *assuming* it does, the tag data is stored as a tree in `pphrase->pProperties`.

Comment: Thanks Eric , I had to do pphrase->pProperties->pFirstChild->pszName for "string" and pphrase->pProperties->pFirstChild->pszValue for "one" and pphrase->pProperties->pFirstChild->pNextSibling->pszName for "Name" and pphrase->pProperties->pFirstChild->pNextSibling->pszValue for "first"